# How can I stop creeps from spawning in DotA?

Tags: dota

Can somebody please tell me how to prevent creeps from spawning in DotA? I have Googled it but can't find a command that will achieve this.

I have tried `-killall` , `-spawnoff` , `-disablecreepspawn`, but nothing helps.

Comment: Please refrain from using WoW tags for questions related to DotA in the future ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

- `-killall`: kill all creeps on the map
- `-killsent`: kill all Sentinel's creeps on the map
- `-killscourge`: kill all Scourge's creeps on the map
- `-spawnoff`: disable the spawn of creeps

However these commands will only work **in single player mode**. Which means you can't go in Local Area Network, create a game of DotA and use them. You have to go in single player > custom map (I don't remember the menu's name exactly) and then play a DotA game where you will be able to disable creep spawns.

At the very beginning of the game:

1. Type `-test` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Type the game mode (`-ap`, `-sd` or even `-ardmemomnpfr` if you feel like it) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type `-spawnoff` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The `-spawnoff` command was added in the [6.66 patch](http://www.playdota.com/changelogs/6.66b) and you have here [a list of all the commands you can use](http://www.playdota.com/learn/commands).

Comment: Mate as i have told i have tried all of these commands but nothing works..other commands like cm , dm all are working but not these..

Comment: @waris Check your version of DoTA - you need at least 6.66 and higher. Also, you may have to enable cheats if trying to do this on a Battle.net game (I forget the command for that, but it may just be turning WTF mode on with -wtf).

Comment: @waris Have you explicitly typed "-test" at the begining of the game ? before heroes are loaded in the tavern

Comment: Thanx it worked.